# Angular 6 : Can not load dynamic form

Tags: angular, forms

I want to dynamic load forms but when I click on the button to load the second form I get an error.

As I understand @Viewchild sets the fields property in my child component but does not update that when clicking the button to load the second form.

See also the loadForm method in the app-component.

ERROR
Error: Cannot find control with name: 'userName'

I have a working example in stackbliz.

https://angular-y3n2u9.stackblitz.io

view the console log to see the error message

Anyone has an idea why the second form is not loaded in my demoform-component.

Thanks

John

Comment: can you add your code editor link

Comment: the link is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3n2u9

Answer (score 1):

All primitive types are passed by value. Objects, arrays, and functions are also passed by value so the change detection is not being fired when you load form2  try ngOnChanges life cycle hook it will work.

```
    ngOnChanges(){
         this.dynamicForm = this.createForm();
    }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3n2u9